# Delete function does not work when the value binded is float (with PHP PDO and MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, lamp

I'm working with a simple LAMP stack here. I have this table blue_markers which has a **composite PK** of 2 **float values**. 
In PHP I'm using PDO. I have a class called Blue_marker with a delete method. In another folder there is a script called delete.php. 
Let's look at the code:

**Blue_marker class:**

```
<?php
class Blue_marker {
 public $latitude;
 public $longitude;

//other stuff---------------------------------------------

  public function delete() {
    //create query
    $query = 'DELETE FROM ' . $this->table_name . 
   ' WHERE longitude= :longitude AND latitude= :latitude';
    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // Bind data
    $stmt->bindValue(':longitude', $this->longitude, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':latitude', $this->latitude, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    // Execute query
    if($stmt->execute()) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
}
```

**Delete.php script:**

```
<?php 
 // headers, connection etc.------------------------

  $blue_marker = new Blue_marker($db);

  //get data from request
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);//data from body of the request (PK)
  //pass data
  $blue_marker->latitude = $data['latitude'];
  $blue_marker->longitude = $data['longitude'];

  if ($blue_marker->delete()){
    http_response_code(200);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Blue marker deleted"));
  } else {
    http_response_code(503);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "ERROR occurred. Blue marker NOT deleted"));
  }
?>
```

So what is the problem? The code executes **without an error** (the server returns *200 OK* response, "Blue marker deleted") however nothing is actually deleted. Weird enough this code structure works perfectly with INT or STRING values.

The request looks like: **DELETE** *http://IP_server/.../delete.php*

{
    "longitude": "11.1233997345",
    "latitude": "11.1233997345"
}

P.S.: i could try to change the datatype from FLOAT(10,8) to VARCHAR2(10), but this means that I have to make changes all over my code.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: *i could try to change the datatype from FLOAT(10,8) to VARCHAR2(10)* Not VARCHAR but DECIMAL.

Comment: Change them to `decimal(13,10)` where the 10 determines the precision of the values.

Comment: Many thanks to Akina and Dave for their comments, my problem was solved easily with a simple SQL command:  ALTER TABLE blue_markers
                                                 MODIFY COLUMN latitude DECIMAL(13,10);

Comment: For some reason PHP PDO and MySQL were not too keen to work with FLOAT, prefering DECIMAL

Comment: As well as [the rest of the computer world](https://bitbashing.io/comparing-floats.html)